# Twilio Re-Initialize JS Client when JWT token expires

Tags: angular, twilio

The capability token is set to expire in 60 seconds, so when it is expired I'm trying to re-setup the device

```
twilioDevice = new Twilio.Device();

// I also need incoming calls too, so client has to be refreshed every 60 sec
this.twilioDevice.on('error', error => {
   if (error.code === 31205) {
     this.initilizeTwilio();
   } else {
     this.toastr.warning(error.code + '' + error.message);
   }
});

initilizeTwilio() {
    this.twilioService.getCapability(60).subscribe(data => {
       if (this.twilioDevice.isInitialized) {
           this.twilioDevice.setup(data.capabilitytoken);
       } else {
          this.twilioDevice.setup(data.capabilitytoken, {debug: true});
       }
 }
```

For the first time setup work fine, when token is expired `.setup()` called, is there any other method which needs to invoked? What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

[Twilio Reference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device#method-reference)

Comment: In the timestamps in your image, you create the device and set it up the first time, you then get the error 60 seconds later (as expected) but also 62 seconds later. Are you caching and returning the same, expired token? Also, are you using Capability Tokens or Access Tokens? I'd recommend using Access Tokens as the capability token is deprecated now.

Comment: Got it, `cache` was the issue

Comment: @philnash [Capability](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/capability-tokens) docs doesn't state that it is deprecated, but it is mentioned [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript)

Comment: @philnash could you provide a estimate date when capability tokens will be completely deprecated?

Comment: The [documentation for Twilio Client lists the capability token as deprecated](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device#setup) though there is no estimate for when it will be removed. I'd still recommend upgrading to Access Tokens so that you won't have an issue in the future though. If you're using a Twilio helper library then it should be a fairly straightforward change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I added it as a comment, but I wanted to call out the answer here.

In the timestamps in your image, you create the device and set it up the first time, you then get the error 60 seconds later (as expected) but also 62 seconds later. So it looks as though there is a caching issue on your server side.

If you are looking to take incoming calls, you might consider lengthening the timeout for your access token too.